# SQLite Databases

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I am fairly new to programming java and I just started working with SQLite databases. A school assignment is requiring me to create a stand alone GUI program that can store data. After some research, I will be using a SQLite manager downloaded from Firefox. After completing my project, will it still able to run stand alone? Or will the SQLite manager be required to input data. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you include the respective SQLite libraries. In fact there is little need for the SQLite Manager although the resultant file could be copied and used.

In short the SQLite database is a file that you open (connect to) using the respective library functions/API. Noting that some functionality may depend upon the version of SQLite (which could well be lower on the SQLite Manager).

You could also manage without the SQLite Manager, creating the database and tables therein within the program. Generally you'd use a SQLite Manager to provide a pre-populated database (noting that if using a pre-populated database that identifiers (table and column names) should match (case doesn't matter)).